# Filtering Get-BrokerApplication not working

Tags: powershell, citrix

I want to only filter on certain applications that start with MS but I'm getting an error. Thanks in advance.

```
$Applist = Get-BrokerApplication -AdminAddress DDC -filter "MS"
foreach ($app in $Applist)
{
    Add-XAApplicationAccount $app -accounts "domain\users
}
```

Comment: Add-XAApplicationAccount : Could not connect to net.tcp://servername:2513/Citrix/XenAppCommandsRemoting. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 
00:00:02.0002000. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it IPaddress:2513. 
At line:6 char:9
+         Add-XAApplicationAccount -ComputerName servername-BrowserName $app ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-XAApplicationAccount], EndpointNotFoundException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a read up on the filter syntax of those cmdlets [here](http://support.citrix.com/proddocs/topic/citrix-broker-admin-v2-xd7/about_broker_filtering-xd7.html). It works similar to how regular PowerShell cmdlets treat filter. One of the examples from the site

> `Get-<Noun> -Filter 'Name -like "High*" -or (Priority -eq 1 -and Severity -ge 2)'`

I would guess that the error you are getting is about the format of the input for filter being incorrect. You need to be using similar syntax to what I show above. So a guess would be

```
Get-BrokerApplication -AdminAddress DDC -filter 'Name -like "MS*"'
```